# Highlighting double backslash using listings with texcsstyle

Tags: listings, highlighting

I've got a question (it's in the title) about listings that I do not believe have been answered anywhere (either that or my Google-fu isn't that sufficient). Before I knew of `texcsstyle`'s star option, I tried to highlight double backslash (`\\`) by using the `literate` option (how monstrous):

```
literate=*{\\\\}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}}}}{1}
```

With this I used to be able to highlight double backslash but since I didn't use `texcsstyle` I could not highlight the backslash that comes before all LaTeX commands. But when I finally DO use `texcsstyle`, the `literate` option suddenly no longer works for double backslash, even though all the other `literate` replacements (for `&`,`[`,`]`,`{`,`}`,...) still work. I guess `texcsstyle` is interfering with the `literate` option? How do I resolve this? Is it even possible to have both `texcsstyle` and double backslash highlighted?

Edit: added an example, sorry. Uncomment the line with texcsstyle and you will see the double backslash stop getting highlighted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{charter}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
  moretexcs={includegraphics,multicolumn,multirow,newcolumntype,intertext,},
  morekeywords=[2]{figure,tabular,tabulary,document,minipage,verbatim,table,
    enumerate,tikzpicture,preview},  
  % texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{darkred},
  literate=
            *{\{}{{\textcolor{myblue}{\{}}}{1}
            {\}}{{\textcolor{myblue}{\}}}}{1}
            {\&}{{\textcolor{red}{\&}}}{1}
            {\\\\}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}}}}{1}
            {[}{{\textcolor{myblue}{[}}}{1}
            {]}{{\textcolor{myblue}{]}}}{1},
}
\lstset{language=mytex}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color{purple}\bfseries,
keywordstyle=[2]{\color{magenta}},
commentstyle=\color{darkgreen}, 
stringstyle=\color{orange},
identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
showstringspaces=true,
breaklines=true,
tabsize=4,
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces=true,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle1}
\begin{document}



\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   y & = -4   & + 3 & +4     & -7      \\
   y & =      & + 3 &        & -7      \\
   \intertext{therefore}
   a & = b    & d   & = cccc & e & = d \\
   a & = bbbb & d   & = c    & e & =   \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185169/how-can-i-highlight-properly-in-latex-listings

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way of doing it. It's not particularly elegant, but does the work. The idea is to make `\\` into a normal letter and then use `keywords` instead of `texcs`. Of course, with this way of doing things, you have to re-add by hand all the LaTeX keywords (but copy/paste from the listings source files would make that easy).

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
  alsoletter={\\,*,\&},
  morekeywords={\\begin,
                \\end,
                \\intertext,
                \\\\,
                \&},  
  morekeywords=[2]{figure,
                   tabular,
                   tabulary,
                   document,
                   minipage,
                   verbatim,
                   table,
                   enumerate,
                   tikzpicture,
                   preview,
                   alignat*},  
  literate=*{\{}{{\textcolor{myblue}{\{}}}{1}
            {\}}{{\textcolor{myblue}{\}}}}{1}
            {[}{{\textcolor{myblue}{[}}}{1}
            {]}{{\textcolor{myblue}{]}}}{1},
}

\lstset{language=mytex}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{red},
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{magenta}},
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen}, 
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=true,
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=4,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true,
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   y & = -4   & + 3 & +4     & -7      \\
   y & =      & + 3 &        & -7      \\
   \intertext{therefore}% comment
   a & = b    & d   & = cccc & e & = d \\
   a & = bbbb & d   & = c    & e & =   \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```