# How can I highlight \[...\] properly in LaTeX listings?

Tags: listings, delimiters

The `listings` package provides the option `moredelim`, allowing for custom styles for words enclosed by given delimiters. I would like to give `$...$`, `\[...\]` and `$$...$$` custom colors. `\[...\]`, however, doesn't seem to work well. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
commentstyle=\slshape\color{blue},%
texcsstyle=*\bfseries,%
delim=[s][\color{purple}]{$}{$},%
moredelim=[s][\color{purple}]{\[}{\]},%
moredelim=[s][\color{purple}]{$$}{$$},%
moredelim=[is][\slshape\color{violet}]{@@}{@@}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin[@@opt_par@@]{@@obl_par@@}
    bla
\end{x}
\[math mode\]
$$math mode$$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: result]

I would like to put `\[...\]` fully in color, without interfering `[...]`s. The optional parameter `opt_par` should appear just as `obl_par` (again, `[...]` seems to be problematic). I have tried several variations of `moredelim`, to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `texcsstyle` key modifies the way `listings` processes backslash characters. Actually, because the font you're using (LaTeX's default font, Computer Modern) doesn't come with a boldface typewriter version,

```
texcsstyle=*\bfseries,
```

has no effect on the style of your listings. If you can afford not to customise the style of control sequences (e.g. `\begin`), just don't use the`texcsstyle` key at all, and you should be able to highlight `\[...\]` as you want.

Also, note that, in the definition of delimiters, you need to escape backslash characters:

```
moredelim = [s][\color{purple}]{\\[}{\\]},
```

For more details about which characters must be escaped in values passed to `listings` keys, see subsection 4.1 of the `listings` manual:

> If you want to enter one of the special characters `{}#%\`, this character must be escaped with a backslash. This means that you must write `\}` for the single character 'right brace'—but of course not for the closing paramater character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    language     = [LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle   = \ttfamily,%
    commentstyle = \slshape\color{blue},
    delim        = [s][\color{purple}]{$}{$},
    moredelim    = [s][\color{purple}]{\\[}{\\]},
    moredelim    = [s][\color{purple}]{$$}{$$},
    moredelim    = [is][\slshape\color{violet}]{@@}{@@},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin[@@opt_par@@]{@@obl_par@@}
    bla $x_1$
\end{x}
\[math mode\]
$$math mode$$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```